# How to stop build through dockerfile when unit test failed (Dockerfile + .NET Framework + Nunit Test + Docker Window Container

Tags: asp.net, powershell, unit-testing, dockerfile, docker-build

I have to build stop when unit test fail through docker file.  I am using .NET Framework (not Dot.Net Core).  I have to write command either in power shell script or Docker file (if Unit test fail then build should be stop before execute next line of docker file.

.NET Framework 4.7.2
Docker Window container only
Unit test project (Nunit)
Asp.Net WebForms (old) 
Nunit test runner

Steps, 
I have create project for Unit test  + WebForm + Class library. 
I have created powershell script for run unit test project using Nunit test runner.
I have added path for script in docker file.

I have attached Docker file and power-shell script .

```
 Docker file code here
`# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-20200512-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
WORKDIR /src

COPY ./POC.Web/POC.Web.csproj ./POC.Web/
COPY ./POC.Entites/POC.Entites.csproj ./POC.Entites/
COPY ./POC.Business.Layer/POC.Business.Layer.csproj ./POC.Business.Layer/
COPY ./POC.UnitTests/POC.UnitTests.csproj ./POC.UnitTests/
COPY ./POC.UnitTests/packages.config  ./POC.UnitTests/
COPY ./MttcPoc.sln .

RUN nuget restore MttcPoc.sln

COPY . .
RUN msbuild POC.UnitTests/POC.UnitTests.csproj /p:OutputPath=c:/out/tests 

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';"]

# testResult variable using in shellscript to get the result of unit test
ENV testResult="Passed"

RUN nuget install NUnit.Runners

COPY ./startuptest.ps1 /
RUN /startuptest.ps1
#RUN IF $testResult == "Passed"  EXIT 0 ELSE EXIT -1
RUN if [ "$testResult" = "Passed" ] ; then true ; else false; fi
ENTRYPOINT ["powershell", "/startuptest.ps1"]

#***************************************************** 
#Below line should not execute if unit test fail

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-20200512-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 

ENV APP_ROOT=/inetpub/wwwroot `
    CONNECTIONSTRINGS_CONFIG_MAP="" `
    dockercomposeKey="From Docker file"

WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}
RUN Import-Module WebAdministration; ` 
    Set-ItemProperty -Path 'IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool' -Name processModel.identityType -Value LocalSystem; ` 
    New-WebApplication -Name 'app' -Site 'Default Web Site' -PhysicalPath $env:APP_ROOT

COPY ./startup.ps1 /
RUN /startup.ps1
#ENTRYPOINT ["powershell", "/startup.ps1"]

COPY --from=build c:/out/_PublishedWebsites/POC.Web ${APP_ROOT}
#************************************************************************`

    Powershell script code here

$ProjectDir = "."
$OutDir = "$ProjectDir\testresults"
$testProjectPath = "c:\out\tests\POC.UnitTests.dll"

# Set nunit path test runner
$nunit_path = "$ProjectDir\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.11.1\tools\nunit3-console.exe"

# Run NUnit3 tests
& $nunit_path $testProjectPath --framework=net-4.7.2 --work=$OutDir

[XML]$resultDetails = Get-Content .\$OutDir\TestResult.xml
Write-Output $resultDetails
$string = "test-run"
Write-Output $resultDetails.$string.result
$env:testResult = $resultDetails.$string.result
#Passed
#Failed

#Below line added for if test fail then exit from docker build 
If ($resultDetails.$string.result  -eq 'Passed')  {
    Write-Output "Test passed"
    Write-Output $env:testResult
   return true  
    }else{
        Write-Output "Test failed"
        Write-Output $env:testResult
        return -1
    }
```

Comment: I have done google search for solution but did not get it yet. Kindly request, please help/guide on this

Comment: Hello Expert's, i am waiting, kindly help